# Exporting C# Applications to clients - Confusion about imports

Tags: c#, .net, requirements

I never really understood the technical requirements for C# applications.
I know Windows 10 has some .NET-versions installed by default. But whenever i write a console-application in c# and copy the compiled .exe-file to another computer, the .exe-file never runs (doesnt matter if compiled with net-core or net-framework). It is always missing a lot of dependencies. So I always either have to copy a huge amount of dll-files into the same folder as the .exe-file or publish it as a standalone-application, which is ridicilous huge (130 MB .exe-file for 100-line application which does nothing special at all).

On the other hand i can create a windows-service, compile it and use it. The compiled service-exe is very small (around 30 kb) and can be installed via cmd.exe ("sc create  [...]"). I tested this on a windows 10 VM. It runs without problems.

Am I getting everything right? Why can windows-services run without the .dll-files, but console-applications can not? Since Windows 10 has a lot of .net-applications installed, i would assume every c# application should run on windows 10 without having to add the .dll-files.

Comment: What runtime are you targeting?

Comment: .net 5.0. but i have this problem with all runtimes (.net-framework or .net core)

Comment: for .net 5, you can target a standalone installation.

Comment: The .Net 5 runtime is not pre-installed on any version of Windows.

Comment: You can also figure out for yourself what version of .Net is installed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Comment: the windows-service is running on 4.6.1.

Comment: Is .Net Framework 4.6.1 installed on the computer where you're running the Windows Service?

Comment: according to the registry, 4.8.04084 is installed (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\V4\Full)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the target computer doesn't have the .Net runtime you are targeting installed, you have two options:

1. Install the runtime, then run the app.
2. Bundle the runtime with the app, either as separate files or all within the same exe.

Option 2 is only available for .Net Core and .Net 5 and higher. For .Net Framework (4 and lower) you must choose option 1.

You can detect what versions of Framework are installed by looking at some registry values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

.Net Framework 4.6.1 is included in Windows 10 (I think base but also version 1511). [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#net-framework-461). This is why your Windows Service ran just fine without you needing to do anything.

You can install the .Net Core/5+ runtime from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/ so that you don't need to include the runtime with the binaries, if you wish.

Comment: thank you, this clarified a lot. so if i'm developing in 4.6.1 i can assume the service runs on every win10 computer, as long as the user didnt manually mess with the .net installations. thank you!